# Replacing lost 2010 Hyundai Elantra Key

Tags: key, replacements

I've recently lost the key for a 2010 Hyundai Elantra of a friend that was parked at my house while they were out of town. I have the fob, but don't have the key itself.

Is it possible to obtain a replacement key without having a "master" key to make a copy from? What is the most economical way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a key to copy, your best bet is to have a Hyundai dealership or a locksmith make a key for you.

Only problem you may run into is they will likely ask for proof of ownership before they will make you a key. Since you are not the owner, you may have to wait until your friend returns (they may have a spare key of which you can pay to have a copy made).

Have no idea what the cost is. This will vary by what area of the world you live in.